# How to calculate price?

Tags: php

Why doesn't my `$total' display any value when I run the code?

[image]

Comment: You are not even echoing `$total`, `$row['total']` is different from `$total`

Comment: Please paste code here not img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
$total=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
?> 
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row["bookname"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["price1"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["cdname"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["price2"]; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row["total"]; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php $total = $total + $row['price1'] + $row['price2']; } ?>
```

Remember :  $row['price1'] and $row['price2'] always be an integer values.

Comment: i had tried it but the value display is 0 rather than the total of bookname and cdname.

Comment: Make sure your bookname and cdname integer. Try below code for assistance.

Comment: $total=0;
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    $total = $total + 2 + 3;
}
echo $total;

Comment: Everything is correct just I changed the position of      
<?php $total = $total + $row['price1'] + $row['price2']; ?> above <tr> and i tend to solved it already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize out side of the while loop

```
 <?php
 $total=0; 
 while ($row = ...
```

AND compute the $total as a running total inside ?PHP tag the echo it outside  the loop to display the accumulated total

```
 $total = $total + $row['price1'] + $row['price1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

first you may want to put your total inside a php block then echo it

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$total` before the while loop. And after computation `echo` it outside the while loop.